# Moongose ready state and aws lambda - cache connection

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, mongoose, lambda

I am trying to implement a connect to database function that uses mongoose (MongoDB), and AWS lambda functions. Best practice, as I understand it, is to cache the database so that the connection can be reused. This, I have working. However, the problem is that the mongoose.readyState variable uses some fixed amount of time to determine if the connection is valid or not.

I was wondering if there is an alternative to .readyState to check if the connection is valid. I know that I can try to run a random query against the database every time I want to reuse the connection. Thus, I could determine if an exception happens or not. However, this feels a little hackish.

Here is my connect to database function:

```html
let cacheDb = null

let options = {
    useMongoClient: true,
    autoIndex: true,
    autoReconnect: true,
    keepAlive: true,
    socketOptions: {
        keepAlive: true,
        autoReconnect: true,
        connectTimeoutMS: 30000
    },
    reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
    reconnectInterval: 200,
    poolSize: 1,
    bufferMaxEntries: 0,
};

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise

module.exports = {
    connectToDatabase: function connectToDatabase(context) {
        context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false

        if (cacheDb && mongoose.connection.readyState == 1) {
            return cacheDb
        }
        else {
            mongoose.connect(process.env['MONGODB_URI'], options, function(error){
                if(error){
                    console.log(error.toString())
                }

                cacheDb = mongoose.connection
                return cacheDb
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea as to an alternative approach?

Comment: How are you returning the connection from inside the callback? How do you use this connection after connectToDatabase?

Comment: Did you find a way to achieve this ? Im also stuck with this

Answer (score 0):

In order to check for a valid connection , you should be checking your cached db serverConfig.isConnected method.

like so:

`if (cachedDb && cachedDb.serverConfig.isConnected()) { ...`

This is according to mongodb, in this helpful article: 
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/optimizing-aws-lambda-performance-with-mongodb-atlas-and-nodejs

Comment: This doesn't address the question, which was geared toward Mongoose. If you're using the standard MongoDB driver then, yes, this is correct.